# Sharing data and forcing locks between threads

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locking, game-engine

A friend and I are making a game engine, in which two AI's are fighting each other. We are trying to set up the game engine thread in such a way that the AI threads cannot do things like slow down the game, or destroy any unit at will etc.

The problem we are having is that we need to share data between the game engine and the AI's. Until now we used `synchronize`, but the AI can then just block the variable and the game engine cannot proceed anymore. Or the AI could choose not to synchronize and crash the game, which is also not what we want.

We have been looking at implementations of Lock, but this seems to assume that the AI will check to see if a variable is locked before using, which a bad AI can of course fail to do.

What we would like to do is look at a predictable time if our data is locked. If it is locked, we disqualify the AI. Otherwise we proceed with the game. The problem with synchronized is then that proceeding is the default and that the game engine will wait until the variable is unlocked and it possibly hangs.

**Question**

How to lock a variable/share data in such a way that you can see if the variable is locked and force the lock? Or is there a solution that does not involve locking?

Comment: See [java.util.concurrent.atomic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html), it might provide enough functionality for your requirements.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.cs.utah.edu/flux/janos/janosvm.html.  I don't know whether the project is up to date but I think you might find it useful.

Comment: _Wow, thanks for all the answers everybody, we are looking into them._

Comment: @Tommos Do not forget to accept an answer if it was helpful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to guarantee this is for AIs to share information in a neutral area where neither system has any control over the code.  This way you can use synchronized or Lock or a concurrent collection but since neither AI can access to the code which holds this information they cannot negatively impact one another.  I would make sure locking is not exposed and is controlled by the shared store.

Answer (score 1):

Please I advise do always read/write the shared data from a synchronize/lock/unlock context
only.

```
What we would like to do is look at a predictable time if our data is locked.
```

Yes you can do this. Use ReentrantLock. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html

It has Api  like

```
 boolean tryLock(); // it will return true if lock available else false

 boolean tryLock(long time, TimeUnit unit) // same as above but will wait for the time 
     // you specify and and also can be interrupted.
```

There are more flavours of locks like ReadWriteLock ..Check whichever suits you requirement best.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the interface **Lock** and its implementations: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html

Also, read the doc for the **java.util.concurrent.locks** package: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your exact requirements are; however, you can have everything related to the "game engine" is done in the "game engine" thread only. It is a similar concept to the UI thread. In the UI thread, long running processes are done in a background threads; however when the UI needs to be updated, then a background thread needs to submit/post the change to the UI thread which then does the change itself.